# I cannot open visual studio 2017 ProcessDPIawareness error

Tags: visual-studio, dpi

I try to open visual studio 2017 and it gives me this error :

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Impossible de charger le type 'ProcessDpiAwareness' à partir de l'assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

### OK

I don't get it, I try to uninstall and reinstall and it doesn't want to install anymore, I did many research and I have yet to find a solution. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I think this is yet another problem with .Net 4.7 update on Windows 7/8/8.1 systems. Try installing the updates in [this web page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4033488/comexception-error-from-wpf-applications-after-the-net-framework-4-7-i). If that doesn't help, try uninstalling .Net Framework 4.7 (instructions to uninstall and reinstall also in the [same web page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4033488/comexception-error-from-wpf-applications-after-the-net-framework-4-7-i))